# Center One Element in Android Layout Relative to the Other Elements

Tags: android, android-layout, margin

Is there a way to have some elements on the layout which would be called "primary" for example and then have another element to be centred relative to those?

Imagine you have two slide out menus at the left and right of the screen and then a content section in the middle that you want to be always at the center of whatever empty space you have.

So if they're both out, it's at the center but if you open the left one, the main section is pushed to the right to still be in the center of the remaining empty space on the screen.

Therefore the menu sections are "primary" because then they determine where the rest of the elements, i.e. the content section, should be .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I've figured out a way to do this:

1. Wrap the whole thing in a RelativeLayout
2. Put the primary ones there
3. Create the secondary RelativeLayout and make it "toRightOf" or "toLeftOf" the primary one(s) and set it to fill_parent both on height and width with zero margin
4. Place whatever you want the content to be in another Relative or Linear layout within the last created RelativeLayout and make it to centerInParent
5. E Voila!

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="0dp" >

<!-- this would contain the "content section" --> 
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/primaryObject" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
        >
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="testButton"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

 <!-- this would be the primary thing -->
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/primaryObject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menuPulloutButton"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_sidebar_button" />
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```